# Write down matrix of T with respect to the ordered basis ${ v_1,v_2,v_3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let 
$ v_1 = (1,2,1) , v_2 = (-2,3,1)$
and let $W$ be the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$. Consider the function

$T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ where $T(x) = proj_w x$

*You may assume that T is a linear transformation*

i) Evaluate $T(4,0,9)$

ii) Evaluate $v_3 = v_2 \times v_1$

iii) **Without calculation**, write down the matrix of $T$ with repsect to the ordered basis $ \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. By drawing a diagram, or otherwise, give reasons for your answer.

iv) Hence of otherwise, find an expression for the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis in $\mathbb R^3$

Hi all,
I don't understand how to get part (iii) and part (iv). For part (i) I get $ \{-1,-3,7\}$ and part (ii) confirms part (i).

*Any help is much appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross product can be computed as a formal determinant:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
i & j & k \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
-2 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=-i-3j+7k
$$
so $v_3=v_1\times v_2=(-1,-3,7)$.

Now you have to express $(4,0,9)=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3$ and $T(4,0,9)=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2$, because $v_3$ is orthogonal to every vector in $W$.

The matrix is very easy to compute: since $Tv_1=v_1$, $Tv_2=v_2$ and $Tv_3=0$, it is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Part (iv) is a standard exercise in change of basis.

Comment: Ahhh I see the light! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the fact that, by definition:
$$
Tv_1=v_1 \qquad Tv_2=v_2 \qquad T v_3=0
$$